# Keeping tab as tab while editing html in Netbeans

Tags: html, netbeans, netbeans-8

I am using NetBeans 8.0.1 for a web project and in html files I am using  with "tab-size" attribute. However NetBeans replaces tabs with white spaces. And this makes "tab-size" attribute meaningless. Is there a way to turn this off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using OSX, so it may look a little different in other OS but it gives the main idea anyway.

Open the "preferences" and make the necessary changes as in below.

[image: Netbeans preferences]